# A div is expanding the width of the page

Tags: javascript, html, css, polymer

I have a one-page site. It is basically a list of sections. One of the section has a button which overlays a dialog when clicked. This dialog ends up expanding the width of the page and a sideways scroll bar is introduced.

This really spoils the look and I'm looking to make the dialog not expand the page.

For reference, it is the same kind of layout as here:

http://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-animated-pages/demos/music.html

I tried setting max-width: 100% and overflow-x: hidden on the problematic section but to no avail.

Here's the problematic section's markup:

```
<section id="music-section">
    <div class="music-container">
        <h1> About Us </h1>
        <h2> The following is our mission statement on campus. </h2>

        <div class="music-row">
            <music-demo></music-demo>
        </div>

        <div class="music-row">
            <music-demo-duplicate></music-demo-duplicate>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

And the CSS:

```
.music-row {
    width: 100%;
    height: 330px;
}

.music-container {
    background: rgb(236, 183, 9);
    padding-top: 1%;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Can you post some of your code? What have you tried?

Comment: You must post your code for us to see what you have done so far..

Comment: Add css
body, html{ overflow:hidden}

Comment: Adding this causes the page to not scroll down. I instead tried overflow-x: hidden; This doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

are you using "position:absolute" in your div?
your elements wouldn't align to your div with position:absolute, other cause may be the size of the div, are using % in the values width and height.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the CSS you provided doesn't correspond to your HTML. If you've got a fluid layout (resizes based on screen/browser size) and the parent container of music-section is width: 100%; or in this case max-width, this can cause problems I've discovered. Often times the child element will expand beyond the parent. What worked for me is this:

```
.music-row {
    width: auto;
    height: 330px;
  }
```

Set your child to auto rather than 100%. I hope it works for you.